# How to ask for 20 numbers in python and, then, print the sum of positives and quantities of negatives?

Tags: python, algorithm

The problem seems very simple but I'm cracking my head over it. It's just an algorithm exercise. This is what I have so far:

```
positivesum = 0

negativeqt = 0

value = int(input(("Enter the numbers: ")))

for _ in range(20):

  value

  if value > 0:

    positivesum = positivesum + value

    print("The sum of positives is ", positivesum)`
```

Also, if someone could translate the same exercise in Javascript, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `value = int(input(("Enter the numbers: ")))` can you elaborate on this line? Are you expecting the user to input 20 numbers in one line? And should they be delimited with commas or spaces? Or did you intend to put that _in_ the loop, and ask for an individual number 20 times?

Comment: My intention was to ask 20 times for a number... But I dont know how it works, i thought range(20) would make 20 inputs but it just repeats 20 times the same input

Comment: I can see how you might arrive at that conclusion. In python `value` is set at the moment you do `value = ...`. So if you want to take a new value in each iteration of the loop, then `value = input(...` needs to be inside the loop, as suggested by several of the answers here

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?
**Python:**

```py
sum_positive_number = 0
negative_number_quantities = 0

numbers = 20
for i in range(numbers):
    number_input = int(input(f'Enter number #{i+1}: '))
    if number_input > 0:
        sum_positive_number += number_input
    elif number_input < 0:
        negative_number_quantities += 1

print('Sum of positive numbers: ', sum_positive_number)
print('Quantities of negative numbers: ', negative_number_quantities)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you put the `input` statement in the wrong place:

```
positivesum = 0
negativeqt = 0

for _ in range(20):
    value = int(input(("Enter the numbers: ")))
    if value > 0:
       positivesum += value
    else if value < 0:
       negativeqt += 1
```

If you only ask for one input then the user can only give you one number. Since you want twenty numbers, you need to put the `input` inside your for-loop so you get a value every time you need a value.

With regard to the difference between calculating `positivesum` and `negativeqt`, you're looking for the total of the positive terms so you need to add them together whereas you only want the quantity of negative terms so we increment once every time we see one.

Comment: that is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Can you explain the negativeqt++ difference from positivesum += value ? How one counts quantity and the other the sum?

Comment: @RodrigoDrebes Ahh, I'm sorry. I accidentally mixed some C# syntax in. That won't compile; let me fix it

Comment: @RodrigoDrebes I updated my answer to include the reasoning for the difference between how we calculate `positivesum` and `negativeqt`. If this answer helped you, please consider upvoting. Also, if this was the best answer, please click on the check mark to let others know.

Answer (score 1):

```py
int_list = [int(inp) for inp in input("Enter 20 numbers: ").split()]
pos_sum = sum(num for num in int_list if num > 0)
neg_quantity = len([num for num in int_list if num < 0])

print(f"{pos_sum=} {neg_quantity=}")
```

## How It Works

`int_list` is something called a list comprehension. When prompted with the input, a user is able to input the 20 numbers, with spaces in between the different numbers due to the call to `split()`. `split()` by default will split by a white space character. `split()` will return an iterable list, so we iterate over that list with `for inp in …`. `int(inp)` will convert each of the numbers from type `str` to type `int`. `input()` returns a string, so this is needed to do number operations

`pos_sum` calls the `sum` built in and passes it a generator expression. It iterates over the list resulting from all of the operations done in `int_list` and only looks for the numbers that are greater than 0. It will add these up, giving us our sum.

`neg_quantity` calls the `len` built in and passes in an iterable list to `len`, constructed through a list comprehension. The resulting list from the comprehension will contain all numbers from `int_list` less than 0, and `len` will return the length of that list, giving us our quantity of negatives

Comment: A good use of list comprehensions and f-strings. The only possible issue I could see is that you're expecting the user to put spaces in between their values and users usually don't do what you expect :)

Comment: @Woody1193 yes that is a valid point 

Answer (score 1):

```py
nums = list(map(int, input('Enter the numbers: ').split()))
pos = sum(num for num in nums if num > 0)
neg = len(num for num in nums if num < 0)
print(pos, neg)
```

`split` the input separated by whitespace by default and map each substring, i.e. number, to its `int`. `list` initializes a list to store the result of of `map`.

Notice that `sum` takes `iterable`. Expressions in the form of `num for num in nums if num > 0` are generators. A generator yields a result one by one according to the condition until it terminates. When a generator expression is passed into a function as an argument, the result is passed as a `tuple` which is `iterable`. Therefore `pos` gives you the sum of all positive numbers in the list. Compared to a list comprehension, generators do not demand extra space and once the result is passed in, python can automatically collect the garbage for you.

This answer explains a little bit more about generator expressions and provides another way to get and store the input.

[sum(iterable,/,start=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum)

[len(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#len)

[map(function,iterable,...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 0):

```
positive = 0
negative = 0
for i in range(-10 , 10):
    print(i)



    if i >= 0:
        positive += i
    elif i <= 0:
        negative += 1
print(positive)
print(negative)
```

Comment: in range you can put any number

Comment: Please don't answer with code only. try to elaborate why and how this approach works, and more importantly solves OPs question.